# sqlalchemy.dialects: "synapse." pyodbc

Tags: sqlalchemy, azure-synapse

Please let me know how to connect to azure synapse with sql alchemy create_engine().
I tried using the connection string same as mssql. But it throws error.

I am able to connect with pyodbc.

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.connect(driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
                   server=server,
                   port=1433,
                   database=database,
                   uid=user_name,
                   pwd=password,
                   autocommit=True)
```

But below code doesn't work:
import sqlalchemy.create_engine

```
engine = create_engine(
    "synapse+pyodbc://scott:tiger@synapse.sql:1433/test?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", 
    fast_executemany=True)
```

Im getting sqlalchemy.dialects: "synapse." pyodbc error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `mssql+pyodbc://…` ?

Comment: (Hint: SQLAlchemy has no built-in dialect named "synapse" so unless you have installed a third-party dialect with that name then `synapse+pyodbc://…` will never work.)

Comment: I have tried "mssql+pyodbc://" but it gives error - "datasource not found"

Answer (score 0):

An exact error trace would have helped in pinpointing the issue. I assume it could be due to the ODBC driver. You can  try the code snippet below

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()
```

#--------------------------------------------------

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib.parse
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    r'Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};'
    r'Server=<synapse dedicated server>.sql.azuresynapse.net;'
    r'Database=<database>;'
    r'Uid=<user>;'
    r'Pwd=<password>;'
    r'Encrypt=yes;'
    r'TrustServerCertificate=no;'
    r'Connection Timeout=30;'
)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)

# Modify the connection_string to match conn_str


test_engine = create_engine(conn_str,echo=True)

sql_query = "SELECT 1 AS test"

# Execute the query
with test_engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(sql_query)
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

[image]